# react axios send headers do api

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

How I can send api request, send file and text with one form.

I use

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
```

but, I get return PHP

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
{"errors":{"userName":["The user name field is required."],"userEmail":["The user email field is required."],"userAbout":["The user about field is required."],"userPhone":["The user phone field is required."]}}
```

I fill all the form input
the problem I use just one FORM to send image and text

my react function

```
onCreate = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const { avatar, userName, userEmail, userPhone, userAbout } = this.state;

        axios
            .post(
                api + "api/profile",
                {
                    avatar,
                    userName,
                    userEmail,
                    userAbout,
                    userPhone,
                },

                {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                        Authorization: reqtoken,
                    },
                }
            )

            .then(
                (response) => {

                    if (response.status == 201) {
                        alert("We will be in touch soon");

                    }
                    if (response.status != 201) {
                        alert("Something wrong");
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("Connection Failure");
                }
            );
        this.resetForm();
    };
```

Comment: Please share the curl equivalent of your request

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use axios like this

```
import axios from 'axios';

const handleFileUpload = (file) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const apiUrl = YOUR_API_URL
    formData.append('file', file)
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
    return axios.post(apiUrl, formData, config)
}
```

Comment: I get the file on php but $request->file return null
I use the headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",

Comment: have you use formdata

Comment: yes I can see the data if I use dd($request->all());